# How the display the data that nested in the array (Laravel Vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Sorry. 
I face some problem on how to display the data that nested in array.(Vue js)
[Here is the return array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtDL.png)
I would to show the data in total_billed_by_year
I tried several other attempts but nothing works.
Could please someone help me out with this?

```js
getInfo(index){
      this.popup = true;
      this.inquiryForm.total_contractual=this.pageData.ppr_data[index].total_contractual;

      this.inquiryForm.bil_year =this.pageData.ppr_data[index].total_billed_by_year[index].bil_year;
      this.inquiryForm.bil_total_amount =this.pageData.ppr_data[index].total_billed_year.bil_total_amount;
    },
```

```html
<vs-popup :active.sync="popup">
    <div class="vx-row mb-base">
          <div class="vx-col lg:w-1/2 w-full mb-base">
           <vx-card
              title="Total Bill"
              icon="/images/task.png"
              headerClass="bg-dark pb-6"
              titleColor="#fff"
              subtitleColor="#fff"
            >
              <template slot="no-body">
                <div
                  id=""
                  class="transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out p-4"
                >
                      <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-1"> 
                   <div class="mt-5 ml-2">
              <h5>Total Contractual Amount</h5>
              <div class="text-lg">
              <div v-if="inquiryForm.total_contractual">
                <div>RM {{inquiryForm.total_contractual}} </div>
              </div><div v-else>-</div></div>
            </div>
              <div class="mt-5 ml-2">
              <h5>Bill {{inquiryForm.bil_year}} </h5>
              <div class="text-lg">
                <div>RM {{inquiryForm.bil_total_amount}}
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
              </template>
            </vx-card>
          </div>
          </div>
      </vs-popup>
```

```html
 <vs-list-item
class="hover:shadow"
v-for="(tr, index) in ppr"
v-bind:key="index" 
>
 <template slot="subtitle">
  <div @click="getInfo(index)" class="cursor-pointer">{{tr.id}}</div>
 </template>{{tr.total_billed_by_year[index].bil_year}}
 <span class="font-bold truncate overflow-auto">{{tr.month}} -{{tr.year}} 
<p v-for="(bill,ind) in tr.total_billed_by_year" v-bind:key="ind">
 {{bill.bil_year}}{{bill.bil_total_amount}}
  </p>
</span>
</vs-list-item>
```

Comment: This is due to the data being returned is a string not an object. How are you getting this data? You should not need to do anything to it just return the array/object via laravel. otherwise if its json stored in a db you may have to json_decode before returning it.

Comment: your data is not correct. can you share laravel code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be make your column `total_bil_year` to return as a array via casting from its model. Something like below **(if total_billed_by_year column is a json column)**

```
 protected $casts = [
        'total_billed_by_year' => 'array'
    ];
```

Based on the image you attached to the question shows that it is returned as a json. So you can convert it as object at vue also. Something like below

`JSON.parse(tr.total_billed_by_year)` which will convert into a array and that array contain the object. See the below image. I just reproduced it at console

[image]

you can use it like below. Or just make a function to convert your jsons to objects where you can use it when you want

```
 </template>{{JSON.parse(tr.total_billed_by_year)[0].bil_year}}
```

Comment: Hi, i can get the data already. But now i face some problem. The data first is display in the vs-list. When click on the list it only show all the data in the vs-popup. The the bill year and amount does not show it. I dont know how to pass the value of bill year and amount to the popup. This is how i pass the data to the vs-popup modal.   this.inquiryForm.total_billed_by_year =this.pageData.ppr_data[index].total_billed_by_year[index].bil_year;
      this.inquiryForm.bil_total_amount =this.pageData.ppr_data[index].total_billed_year.bil_total_amount;

Comment: mm looks likw you just want to fix all the issues by us. I have provided a answer which helps to your question. Rest of others would be based on your requirements. If my answer helped you please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

baby, using `JSON.parse(yourJSONString)` to transform your json string to json object.